# Frechet derivative of function $\mathbb{R}^n \ni x \mapsto (\mathbb{R}^n \ni y \mapsto e^{-\|x - y\|} ) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> For an integer $n \geq 1$, consider the function $$f : \mathbb{R}^n \to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n), \quad f(x) := e^{-\|x - \cdot\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}}. $$

> I want to know whether $f$ is (Frechet) differentiable, and what its derivative is.

I am not exactly sure how to proceed with this question. I was thinking that $f$ is differentiable because the function $\|x - \cdot\|$ is differentiable, but I do not know how to compute the derivative of $f$.

I was thinking that I could somehow apply the chain rule by first determining the derivative of the map $$\mathbb{R}^n \ni x \mapsto \|x - \cdot\| \in C(\mathbb{R}^n), $$ but I do not think that this function is differentiable.

I also tried writing $f(x) = \tau_x g$, where $$g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n, g(y) := e^{-\|y\|}, $$ and where $\tau_x$ is the translation by $x$ operator, which is continuous in $x$ but I do not think that it is differentiable in $x$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $e^{-\|x - \cdot \|_{\Bbb R^n}}$? In order to exponentiate an operator, it needs to map some space to itself, but $\|x - \cdot\|_{\Bbb R^n}$ is a map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: the map $F:x \mapsto \|x - \cdot\|$ is (in a sense) differentiable wherever $x \neq 0$. To see that this is the case, note that
$$
F(x + h)(a) - F(x)(a) = \\
\|x + h - a\| - \|x -a\| = \\
[\|x-a\|^2 + 2 \langle x-a,h \rangle + \|h\|^2]^{1/2} - \|x-a\| =\\
\frac 1{\|x-a\|} \langle x-a,h \rangle + o(\|h\|).
$$
So, we have $(DF(x))(h) = \langle \frac{x-\cdot}{\|x - \cdot\|},h\rangle$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann This is not the exponential of any operator; the map $e^{-\|x - \cdot\|}$ is just the map that takes $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and maps it to $e^{-\|x - y\|} \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the map $F:x \mapsto \exp(-\|x - \cdot\|)$ is (in a sense) differentiable. To see that this is the case, note that
$$
F(x + h)(a) = \\
\exp(-\|x + h - a\|) = \\
\exp(-[\|x-a\|^2 + 2 \langle x-a,h \rangle + \|h\|^2]^{1/2})= \\
\exp\left[-\|x-a\| - \frac 1{\|x-a\|} \langle x-a,h \rangle + o(\|h\|) \right] =\\
\exp(-\|x-a\|) - 
\frac {\exp(-\|x-a\|)}{\|x-a\|} \langle x-a,h \rangle + o(\|h\|) = \\
F(x)(a) + \frac {\exp(-\|x-a\|)}{\|x-a\|} \langle x-a,h \rangle + o(\|h\|).
$$
So, we should have $(DF(x))(h) = \exp(-\|x-\cdot\|)\langle \frac{x-\cdot}{\|x - \cdot\|},h\rangle$.